# Error with mysql (error 1136)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got this little problem with my database.

I have created a table '`articoli`' that contains the brand, the model and the price of the articles.

Every article is defined by an `id` (ID_ARTICOLO)` that is an auto increment field.

Well now when I try to insert some data, I don't specify the `id` because it is auto increment, but I have got back an error that says:

> "Error SQL (1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

That means I forget a field, and the only one I don't specify on my query is the `id`. Why do I get that error if the `id` is an auto increment field?

Answer (score 1):

If your insert statement doesn't provide **all** the columns, you need to explicitly list all the columns you **are** providing, even if the one you're leaving out is auto-incrementing:

```
INSERT INTO articoli
(brand, model, price)
VALUES ('myBrand', 'myModel', 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try as soon as possible